# Trigger event on TAB button click in Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a verification in an excel cell ,  so that nobody can leave it empty by clicking a tab button.

So as soon as a user clicks the tab button with the empty cell , it should display a message.

Do You have any clue for that?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If iKeyCode = vbKeyTab Then    
    If CancSelEvnt = False Then    
        MsgBox (1)        
    Else 
        If IsEmpty(Cells(Target.Row, 7).Value) = True Then   
            MsgBox ("This cell should not be kept empty.")    
        End If       
    End If    
End If

End Sub
```

Just want any error message as soon as user moves from one cell to another cell in same row (using tab key)

Comment: I wouldn't wait for a tab keypress because the user could press the arrow keys as well, right? Maybe just add global variables to track the previous row/column and compare the target.row and target.column to those instead?

Comment: Perhaps another way to do this is create a dropdown of options in data validation, and set "Ignore blanks" to false. Then it will throw an error every time the user wants to leave the cell without a value being selected.

Answer (score 2):

Run this command:

```
Sub EnableTab()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}", "TabPressed"
End Sub
```

And whenever <kbd>Tab</kbd>is pressed, the `TabPressed` Sub would be executed:

```
Sub TabPressed()
    Debug.Print "MsgBox!"
End Sub
```

To disable it run this:

```
Sub DisableTab()
    Application.OnKey "{TAB}", ""
End Sub
```

If it should be in a workbook, then consider writing `Application.OnKey` in the events of the workbook:

- `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)` for the `EnableTab`
- `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` for the `DisableTab`
- [Application.OnKey Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.onkey)

Comment: Also noteworthy (since it catches me out every time): When this is enabled (after the first code is ran) it will trigger every time you press TAB in excel, no matter what workbook you are in, it will trigger in every workbook until it is disabled with the last macro, or excel is closed completely.